# Need to "react" on any sound initiated

Tags: java, audio, monitoring

I need to be able to launch certain procedure only when there is some sound output initiated. This is like when some sound is "beeped" (having complete silence before). I image for this to handle is somehow to monitor the strength of the output channel (where usually all sound is outputted), and if it reaches the certain border, I will launch my "procedure". The sound can be initiated by any program in the system, I just need to monitor the output strength and react.
Is there a way to make such "monitor" in java?
Thanks.

Comment: *Any* sound on that computer or only a sound initiated by your program?

Comment: As I mentioned "The sound can be initiated by any program in the system", for example a song started to play, or a beep in the game